# Function created from a string does not see parent scope

Tags: javascript

In my app I have some functions wrapped in a module. To run any of these functions I send a request to the server which responds with a string like this "foo({bar: 'baz'})". Then I make a new function from this string and run it. The problem is that the new function does not see a scope it is in. Here is a simplified example:

```
var foo = (function () {

  function bar (fnbody) {
    // this one runs
    var baz = function() { greet1(); };
    baz();

    // this one does not
    var doit = new Function(fnbody);
    doit();
  }

  function greet1() {
    alert('ALOHA!');
  }
  function greet2() {
    alert('SAWADEE!');
  }


  return {
    bar: bar
  };

})();

foo.bar('greet2();');
```

Here is the [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/luparutuqose/3/edit?js,console).

Can anyone please explain me why greet2() is not defined?
How can I make this kind of thing work keeping functions greet1 and greet2 private to the module?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Quoting the big yellow box form the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function): *"**Note:** Functions created with the `Function` constructor do not create closures to their creation contexts; they always are created in the global scope."*

Comment: I appreciate all the answers guys! I guess I should stick with eval:   var doit = function() { return eval(fnbody); };
    doit();

Comment: @cyxou no, probably not. Look into [rpc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call).

Comment: @naomik, that is exactly what I was trying to implement myself ))) Now I'm gonna use one of the ready-made JSON-RPC libraries. Thanks a lot for the useful hint:)

Answer (score 6):

It's simply how the `Function` constructor works. Functions created using it are created in the global scope instead of the local scope where it was defined.

This is the expected behavior. You'd have to use `eval()` to create a function from a string that can access local variables.

From **ES5 [15.3.2.1 new Function (p1, p2, … , pn, body)](http://es5.github.io/#x15.3.2)**, the final step reads:

> *"11. Return a new Function object created as specified in 13.2 passing P as the FormalParameterList and body as the FunctionBody. **Pass in the Global Environment as the Scope parameter** and strict as the Strict flag."*

Answer (score 5):

From [MDN Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)

> Note: Functions created with the Function constructor do not create closures to their creation contexts; they always are created in the global scope. When running them, they will only be able to access their own local variables and global ones, not the ones from the scope in which the Function constructor was called. This is different from using eval with code for a function expression.

If you want server/client to call functions on either side, perhaps you should look into some sort of Remote Procedure Call (RPC).

[JSON-RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-RPC) might interest you. There's also a big list of implementations for you to pick from.

Comment: That only answers part of the question.